# How can I turn off a Cisco modem/router's "Wi-Fi Protected Setup"?

Tags: wireless-router, dsl-modem, wps

My modem/router, a Cisco EPC3925, has something called "Wi-Fi Protected Setup" or "WPS", preventing me from changing certain settings. This includes turning wireless off altogether.
This feature hands over control of said settings to my ISP. Thus, if I want to turn of wireless, I need to contact them.
I'd like to turn off this "WPS", so I regain control. There is a checkbox on the web interface for "manual" control, but it is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log into your router through IE or chrome.. etc e.g. http://x.x.x.x 

Then follow these steps.

1. Go to wireless
2. Basic settings
3. there should be a configuration type manual/WPS

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to this, make sure "Wireless Network" is enabled, or you won't be able to change the setting.